# AWS Athena - explain query plan

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

Can I use 'explain' statement in AWS Athena? (For reviewing query's plan)
I tried to use explain statement in Athena, but I met below error message.

Your query has the following error(s):

Queries of this type are not supported (Service: AmazonAthena; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidRequestException

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/other-notable-limitations.html) EXPLAIN statements are not supported in Athena as of now.If you want to perform the same then you can do it in EMR-Presto by [integrating](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-presto-glue.html) it with AWS Glue catalog.

Answer (score 3):

EXPLAIN statement is now supported by Athena. You can find more information in [AWS documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/athena-explain-statement.html).